# Can you lock screen from your app?

Tags: android

Is it possible to lock the screen from an app?

ie, just like pressing the power button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup I think you could.  Take a look at [that lock screen class](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/policies/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java;hb=HEAD) . also you 'd take a look at the [related class](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/policies/base.git;a=tree;f=phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl;h=4538fd8ceb112de02ffb1a622bc00c89d48c5f62;hb=HEAD).

Comment: None of this is part of the Android SDK. Do not use it.

Comment: You can, however, see that the indicated class points toward the lock / unlock mecanism

Comment: Both links are invalid, which confirms stackoverflow rules to write-down answers instead of putting links.