# How to programmatically lock screen in Android?

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lock the android device programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically)

How can I programmatically lock the screen in Android?

Answer (score 15):

Check this class : [com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockScreen](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/policies/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java;hb=HEAD)

Referenced from here: [Can you lock screen from your app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219950/can-you-lock-screen-from-your-app)

Also check code for enabling and disabling lock Screen in Android. (Referenced from [here](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/03/enabling-and-disabling-lock-screen-in.html))

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
```

**For locking the screen use,**

```
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

**and for disabling the lock use,**

```
lock.disableKeyguard()
```

Comment: i test this code,but this not working

Comment: Can you share code what you tried? and What issues you are facing with it ?

Comment: This code will not work on SDK 8 and above do use Adams suggestion on using device policy manager.

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 4):

In order to do this you need to use the [Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#top) API that was added in (I think) 2.2. Once your app is registered on the device as a device administrator, you can then use DevicePolicyManager.lockNow() to lock the screen. The DeviceAdmin sample application in the SDK is a good place to look as well.