# Lock the screen in android

Tags: android, lockscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to programmaticaly lock screen android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594532/how-to-programmaticaly-lock-screen-android)

Hie team gud eve, I have tried using keygaurdmanager its executing, but what i need is when i click on the application the screen should be locked immediately. can any one suggest me how its possible..

Like: Lock app in android market

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

**This will help you ::**

```
KeyguardManager mgr = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = mgr.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

[**For more description**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is executing But i need to lock the whole device Like https://market.android.com/details?id=com.droidmania.lockscreenwidget&feature=search_result

Comment: put this code in service and make it booting time so when you start your phone execute this portion and locking shown initially