# My own App as Lockscreen in ANDROID

Tags: android, lockscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android lock screen source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140964/android-lock-screen-source-code)

I´ve created an app, that contains 2 activities. One is to setAPassword and the other is to realize the login. How can i place this App as LockScreen in Android? It should permanentely run.

Comment: There is a similar question  here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140964/android-lock-screen-source-code

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess of mine

1. disable back key
2. disable home key
3. No menu
4. Listen Boot Start of device and launch your screen again
5. only on successful login call finish()

for task 1,2,3 search stackoverflow . They are there for sure..

Also there are option in android for making your own home screen/ launcher screen.
for e.g go_launcher app in android

for disabling home key try this 
full activity code is

```
package com.lockscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class LockScreenActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager
            .newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add("Exit");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle().equals("Exit")) {
        finish();
        System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

manifest needs permission

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: will like to know how 2nd can b done.

Comment: ahhhhh i hate -1.  god bless me with some multiple +1

Comment: @vincent check the code section

Comment: as far as I know you cant disable the  home key unless your app is a Homescreen app

Comment: @sherif try the code i wrote above

Comment: @sherif : i agree,back press can be easily manipulated but not home...

Comment: sherif and @Vincent try the code and let me know what you saw.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3594553/1075066  from here i found http://stackoverflow.com/a/3219978/1075066

Comment: Fortunately, your "block the home key" solution no longer works, as of Android 4.0.

Comment: @CommonsWare we can start service in background to check our screen is in foreground or not. if not bring it up.

Comment: we can also go for a server heart beat mechanism send a push if heart beat is not received to re launch app. there must be some hack for 4.0 too.

Comment: i can also think of calling new activity in onPause onStop or onDestroy. will give it a shot too

Comment: i know these are not good steps from the perspective of this platform policies.but bringing these points in front will lead to its fix in newer versions :)

Comment: @Javanator: Fortunately, all your other techniques are trivially defeated as well, to the extent they would ever work reliably in the first place. I can teach my nephews how to get past these so-called "lockscreens", and my nephews are aged 9 and 6.

Comment: @CommonsWare fortunately many didn't get uncle like you so they won't get past these so-called "lockscreens" even if they are aged 90 or 60.